# Different combinations of groups of words in a sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, set, combinatorics

I am trying to come up with an algorithm for determining all of the combinations of word groupings in a sentence (not breaking the order of the words).

e.g. With this sentence: "the test case phrase"
The different combinations (splitting on any number of space(s)) would be:

```
['the test case phrase']
['the' , 'test case phrase']
['the test' , 'case phrase']
['the test case' , 'phrase']
['the' , 'test' , 'case phrase']
['the test' , 'case' , 'phrase']
['the' , 'test case', 'phrase']
['the' , 'test' , 'case' , 'phrase']
```

I was initially thinking permutations but from what I can tell that would be if I was seeking any re-ordered combination of the set.

I feel like there is a mathematical principal at work here but I just can't put my finger on it...

FYI: I was writing my test cases and plan to implement the solution in Javascript

Comment: I tried to be as specific as I could by giving an example and specifying the restrictions of the particular problem while not making the solution not only apply exactly to me. Using search, I wasn't able to locate any duplicate questions/solutions where the order of the test case needed preserved. Is it the title that is too broad? Please correct me if I am wrong but I thought the goal was make the questions closer to the general side rather than nailed down to a specific question->answer?

Answer (score 4):

The works pretty cleanly as a backtracking recursive function in javascript. You loop through the array and build each item with i to i-1 first parts and within each loop recurse on the rest while adding the results to the array `res`:

```js
let str = "the test case phrase"

function mix(arr, res, start = []) {
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {        // You don't need a base case because when length is 0 the loop won't run
    let rest = arr.slice()                      // make a copy so we don't mess up the input
    let head = rest.splice(0, i).join(" ")      // take the head + the rest for o to i
    res.push([...start, head, rest.join(' ')])  // add it as an entry
    mix(rest, res, [...start, head])            // recurse on the rest
  }
  return res
}
let r = mix(str.split(" "), [str])      // we don't need to calculate the original string, so just start with it.
console.log(r.join('\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the javascript solution, it definitely seems to work for the test case I provided and fits the bill for what I was trying to work out. I haven't used the `[...start` syntax before.

Comment: This is a very nice approach. It seems to scale well also.

Comment: Hey @Twhyler, yeah, the `[...start]` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It's fairly new to Javascript, but is addictive and very convenient once you get used it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem can be solved by applying the concepts of [Star and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Essentially, for our given example, we have four words.  We don't care that they are different, just that they are words. These would be our stars. Now, with four words, we have 3 spaces between them where commas can go (our bars). We initially start with zero commas and work our way up to 3 commas.

For (# of commas) = 0 we have:

```
3! / (0! (3 - 0) !) = 1
```

For (# of commas) = 1 we have:

```
3! / (1! (3 - 1) !) = 3
```

For (# of commas) = 2 we have:

```
3! / (2! (3 - 2) !) = 3
```

For (# of commas) = 3 we have:

```
3! / (3! (3 - 3) !) = 1
```

This gives a total of `1 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 8` word combinations.

To attack this algorithmically you can simply iterate over every combination of spaces and insert commas as you go. This shouldn't be that difficult.

I don't know javascript, so I will give the code in `R` (N.B. I do not recommend the following coding style in `R`.. I wrote it this way to be more transparent for other languages):

```
words = c("the test case phrase")

## trivial case.. no commas
listOfWords = list(words)

## split on spaces
myWords = strsplit(words, " ")[[1]]
count = 1

for (i in 1:3) {

    myCombs = combn(3, i)

    for (j in 1:ncol(myCombs)) {

        tempWords = myWords

        for (k in 1:nrow(myCombs)) {
            tempWords[myCombs[k, j]] = paste(c(tempWords[myCombs[k, j]], ","), collapse = "")
        }

        count = count + 1
        listOfWords[[count]] = paste(tempWords, collapse = " ")
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
listOfWords
[[1]]
[1] "the test case phrase"

[[2]]
[1] "the, test case phrase"

[[3]]
[1] "the test, case phrase"

[[4]]
[1] "the test case, phrase"

[[5]]
[1] "the, test, case phrase"

[[6]]
[1] "the, test case, phrase"

[[7]]
[1] "the test, case, phrase"

[[8]]
[1] "the, test, case, phrase"
```

Comment: Additional clue: there are `2^(n-1)` combinations, every maps to integer in mentioned range (where n is space count)

Comment: This seems like a great solution, I need to spend some time to unpack exactly the R (haven't spent a lot of time with R yet) is doing but I think I understand the implementation.